# Is there a smart way to find an app with the features I want?

Tags: applications, search

Is there a smarter way to find the app I want? Basically, I'm searching the app store for a note-taking app that will suit my needs, and the number of apps is large. So, my approach is to find the note-taking apps and include "sync" and "import" in the search. My goal is to find an app that will both import my existing notes from the default Memo app, and also support syncing with my Google Drive so that I can look at notes on my PC.

But that results in a large list of apps to sift through, looking for the right one. Further, not all the apps fully describe everything they do, and might have the feature I want without mentioning it in the online description. Is this a problem without an automatic solution, or is there a smart alternative to my approach?

Comment: "import the default Memo app" - okay which device/name/package name? Is it possible that the data is encrypted and you won't be able to export/or have to do it manually every time?  Also Google Drive is changing their APIs so do look out for that.

Comment: @morrison-chang Samsung Notes imports from Memo just fine, so I think that's not an issue.

Comment: Maybe [my corresponding app listings](https://android.izzysoft.de/applists/category/named/office_notes) could help here?